# zsh killed the jupyter notebook，how to solve it？

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Yesterday I updated conda on my 1 Mac mini as usual and installed nlgview. Everything is ok but when I wanted to start notebook by "jupyter notebook", the terminal.app gave a short message soon:

"zsh: killed   jupyter notebook".

There was no other information. I can not start notebook any more. What's wrong with my Mac mini? How to solve this problem? Thanks for your time.

My env:
Mac mini Big sur latest version.
Conda built by Miniforge for M1.
All the packages installed by "conda install xxx". Therefore they should be natively supporting M1.
Only the base environment.

Comment: I suspected whether it was caused by the installation of nlgview because it also installed a jupyter extension also...Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what worked for me was running it in bash.
So assuming that you have already installed jupyter via the macOS terminal using `pip3 install jupyter` or `pip3 install jupyter-lab`

Go to bash shell in terminal via the `bash` command and run `jupyter notebook` and it should work.

Cheers!